# D3.js v4.0.0-alpha.35 Transitions not working

Tags: d3.js

I try to mimic this [collapsible tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) using the newest version of d3.js, however I am running into some issues.

The `nodeEnter` part of the code is executing just fine but for whatever reason the `nodeUpdate` aka the transition part of the code will not execute. I look in the console to make sure it wasn't just a visibility issue, I get no errors, nothing... The coordinates stay the same as they were when they were initiated by the `nodeEnter` portion of the code.
My only guess is that something changed with the new version of d3.js and I am missing something...

```js
var t = d3.transition()
.duration(750)
.ease(d3.easeLinear);

var tree = d3.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

function updateDisplay(source){
  
  var treeData = tree(root).descendants(),
      linkData = treeData.slice(1); 
  
  treeData.forEach(function(d) {
    
    /*Normalize for fixed-depth between levels, so that y value 
    **  stays the same through transition as opposed to being 
    **  an even division of the svg width. */
    d.y = d.depth *180;
    
  });
  
                            
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(treeData);

  var nodeEnter = node.enter()
                      .append("g")
                        .attr("class", function(d) {return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");})
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";});
  
  console.log(nodeEnter);
  
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("y", -10)
            .attr("rx", 1e-6)//goes to 8 after transition
            .attr("ry", 1e-6)//goes to 8 after transition
            .attr("width", 1e-6)
            .attr("height", 1e-6)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {return d.children ? "scale(-1,1) translate(-20,0)" : "";})
            .attr("style", "fill:#EEEEEE;filter:url(#dropshadow)");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
            .attr("dy", 3)
            .attr("x", function(d) {return d.children ? -8 : 30;})
            .style("text-anchor", function(d) {return d.children ? "end" : "start";})
            .text(function(d) {return d.id;})
            .each(function(d) {d.NameWidth = this.getBBox().width;})
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  

  var avatar = nodeEnter.append("g").attr("style", "filter:url(#dropshadow)");

  avatar.append("clipPath")
          .attr("id", "avatarClip")
          .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 1e-6)//12.5
            .attr("cy", 1e-6)//12.5
            .attr("r", 1e-6);//12.5

  avatar.append("circle")
          .attr("cx", 1e-6)//12.5
          .attr("cy", 1e-6)//12.5
          .attr("r", 1e-6)//12.5
          .attr("style", "fill:white")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0,-12)");

  avatar.append("image")
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return (d.data.img ? d.data.img : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-342/ic_person_black_48px.svg");})
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#avatarClip)")
          .attr("class", function(d) {return (d.children ? "avatar--manager" : "");})
          .attr("width", 25)
          .attr("height", 25)
          .attr("transform", "translate(0,-12)");  
  
  avatar.on("click", function(d) {toggle(d);});
  
  //TRANSITION OF NODES TO NEW POSITIONS
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition(t)
                        .attr("class", function(d) {return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");})
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";});
  
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {return d.children ? -8 : 30;})
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) {return d.children ? "end" : "start";})
    .text(function(d) {return d.id;})
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
              .attr("transform", function(d) {return d.children ? "scale(-1,1) translate(-20,0)" : "";})
              .attr("height", 20)
              .attr("width", function(d) {return (d.NameWidth + 35);});
  
  nodeUpdate.select("clipPath")
              .attr("cx", 12.5)
              .attr("cy", 12.5)
              .attr("r", 12.5);
  
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
             .attr("cx", 12.5)
             .attr("cy", 12.5)
             .attr("r", 12.5);

  nodeUpdate.select("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return (d.data.img ? d.data.img : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-342/ic_person_black_48px.svg");})
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#avatarClip)")
    .attr("class", function(d) {return (d.children ? "avatar--manager" : "");});
  
  //TRANSITIONING EXITING NODES
  var nodeExit = node.exit()
                     .transition(t)
                     .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";})
                     .remove();
  
  
 
  /*var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                 .data(linkData);*/
  

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
   root.each(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
  
}
```

PS: My code isn't an exact replica of the link above, I put my own spin when it came to design...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There has been a conceptual change of the enter and update selections from v3 to v4. Whereas in v3 the enter selection was automatically merged into the update selection you have to explicitely call `selection.merge()` from v4 upwards to get the same result.

The documentation for [`selection.enter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections#enter) of v3 tells us:

> The enter selection **merges into the update selection** when you append or insert.

The documentation of the same method of v4, on the other hand, reads:

> The enter selection is typically only used transiently to append elements, and is often [merged](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge) with the update selection after appending, such that modifications can be applied to both entering and updating elements.

Have a look at this simplified example using v3, which should come with no surprises:

```js
var update = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
  .data([1]);
  
var enter = update.enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", "50")
    .attr("cy", "50")
    .attr("r", "20")
    .attr("fill", "red");
    
 update
   .transition().duration(2000)
     .attr("fill", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Doing the same with v4 requires a little modification, though:

```js
var update = d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
  .data([1]);
  
var enter = update.enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", "50")
    .attr("cy", "50")
    .attr("r", "20")
    .attr("fill", "red");
    
 update
   .merge(enter)  // This merges both the enter and the update selection
   .transition().duration(2000)
     .attr("fill", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg></svg>
```

Commenting out the `.merge()` line shows the effect you described, because the update selection will be empty, even though you entered new elements using the enter selection before.

Comment: This is tremendous help I have added some things to my post. If you don't mind taking a look at it. @altocumulus

Comment: @Yourinium If this solved your first problem, please revert your edits and post another question. This all about the changes to the enter/update selections and because this is as of now very poorly documented, I got a feeling we are going to see loads of questions about it. I'd like to keep this as concise as possible for future reference.

Comment: Very good point here is the new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310768/d3-js-v4-wacky-link-transition-in-collapsible-tree-example @altocumulus

Comment: thanks, this helped a lot! but what's still unclear to me is how to manage the "exit" - is there some merged needed too?